# Access GET parameters in MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, get

I developed an MVC application and now I need to make some changes. I would like to pass additional parameters and the format of URL cannot be changed. Initially the URL looked like http://url.com/product/1001
Now
It has to be http://url.com/product/1001?type=1

How do I parse type=1 in my Controller module. Kindly help

Answer (score 25):

You can simply add it to the action method signature:

```
 public ActionResult MyMethod(string type)
 {

 }
```

Route, QueryString, Form, and other values automatically get bound to action method signatures if the naming matches and a conversion is possible (so `int?` would also be a valid type for `type`).

If you don't want to do that, you can always fall back to the ever reliable `Request.QueryString[]` NameValueCollection.

```
string type = Request.QueryString["type"];
```

Comment: I made the following change 
public ActionResult Product(int id, int type) {}
But I was unable to do a successful parse. I think I'm doing something wrong